# When should we prefer rounded corner rectangle over square corner rectangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design

I always find myself in a dilemma about whether to choose rounded corners or square corners, for both applications UI & web design.

As I read in a couple of articles choose one style of corners and stick to it throughout the project.

I am new into interface designing.

Comment: Hello user3271415, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I'm sorry to tell you that we prefer concise questions with an objectively correct answer for our Q&A format. Your question seems more like a discussion point, and more of an opinion. It may be closed for that reason. Please, don't be discouraged, we are aware that using this site can be a learning curve, but we *are* happy to have you. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: So if there is a question which might not have one correct answer and could involve discussion, shouldn't we post it? 
I am asking out of curiosity. If it isn't right for this community, Quora is always there.

Comment: The problem is that the question is non-specific. There are so many use cases, so many possibilities that might favor one over the other, that it's impossible to give an definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! 
First, you are right in thinking that if you pick a style you should stick with it throughout the project; it will make for a better graphic unity.

Here is how I would decide:

**What's your topic/client?**
Everytime I make design choices, I always think of the topic or client first. Squares look serious and rounded corners look more friendly. If I'm working on something aimed at kids, I would more likely go for rounded. On the other hand if I'm designing for a big corporation, I would go for normal square corners.

**What's the current trend?**
In the design field or possibly in the field your client is working in, there are trends that you might want to follow to look up to date or to conform. Web 2.0 was famous for its rounded corners. Now with the flat trend, we're seeing more normal squares creep back in interfaces.

It will definitely be a major decision for an interface because it will define the overall ambiance the user will be experiencing.